# Can't get input value with Twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig

Hello I was trying to pass some arguments but I don't know how to get value of input using twig here is my code :
okey first of all im displaying the blog details using this detailsaction which also rendering a form to add comments to the blog ;

```
public function detailsAction(Request $request,Blog $blog){

        $user=$this->getUser();
        if($user==null)
            return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login');
        $add_comment = new CommentaireBlog();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $comments = $em->getRepository(CommentaireBlog::class)->findByBlog($blog);
        $add_comment->setBlog($blog);
        $add_comment->setUser($user);
        $add_comment->setDate( new \DateTime());

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($add_comment)

            ->add('contenu', TextareaType::class)

            ->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $add_comment = $form->getData();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($add_comment);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_details', array('id' => $blog->getId()));
            }
        }


        return $this->render('blog/details.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'comment' => $add_comment,
            'blog' => $blog,
            'comments'=>$comments,
        ));

    }
```

twig page:

```
   {{ form_start(form) }}
                                <div class="row form-group">

                                    <div class="col col-md-3"><label class=" form-control-label">Votre Commentaire  </label></div>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-9"> {{ form_widget(form.contenu, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}<small class="form-text text-muted"></small></div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Envoyer</button>
                                    <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

now what i want to do is that after someone add a comment and its(racist/verbual abuse..) an other user can report the comment and a mail will be sent so i used reportAction which take three arguments the reason the message and comment id

```
public function reportAction($msg,$type,$id)
    {

    }
```

i still didnt write inside it cause first of all i need to the value of inputs so i went to the twig page and i made this little form to get inputs but idk how to get the value 
here is the form :

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form id="lala" method="GET">
    <label for="cars">Reason:</label>
            <select id="reportreason">
                <option value="Inappropriate Content">Inappropriate Content</option>
                 <option value="Spam">Spam</option>
                <option value="Racism">Racism</option>
                <option value="Nudity">Nudity</option>
                 <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="reportmessage" class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <a id="reportlink" href="{{ path('comment_report', { 'msg': form.vars.data.reportmessage ,'type': form.vars.data.reportreason, 'id': comment.id  }) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</a>
</div>
```

this is yml file :

```
blog_details:
    path:      /{id}/details
    defaults: { _controller: "BlogBundle:Blog:details" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
comment_report:
    path:     /{msg}/{type}/{id}/report
    defaults: { _controller: "BlogBundle:Blog:report" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
```

but im getting this error now :
Neither the property "reportmessage" nor one of the methods "reportmessage()", "getreportmessage()"/"isreportmessage()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "BlogBundle\Entity\CommentaireBlog".

so how can i get get the value of the inputs using twig ?

Comment: Have you checked which of these lines throws that error?

Comment: yes its this line <a href="{{ path('comment_report', { 'msg': {form.reportmessage.value} ,'type': {form.reportreason.value }, 'id': comment.id  }) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</a>

Comment: im sure the error coming from  {form.report.message} but idk what to put instead to get the value of the input

Comment: @LouayGourrida I deleted my answer, there are some serious issues with your code that need clarification and addressing (like your form fields are using `id="reportmessage"` instead of `name="reportmessage"`). How are the values for your `path()` initially set without the modal form being submitted? This appears that you're needing a Javascript solution and not a Symfony/Twig solution. Please update your question with the controller action that is rendering the form, so we can see exactly what's going on and clarify how the initial `path()` arguments are expected to be defined.

Comment: @fyrye i jsut updated my code and explained everything i hope it makes some sense now

Comment: im still learning symfony so i dont really know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Twig Object Syntax https://twigfiddle.com/01iobj

Effectively the twig error message is saying that in your `path()` arguments, you are passing an object without an associated key as `{value}` The correct syntax would be `{key: value}` or `[value]`, resembling a JSON syntax.

```
{ 
   "key1": { "key1a": "value1a" }, 
   "key2": ["value2"], 
   "key3": "value3" 
}
```

**Result**

```
$_GET = array(
    'key1' => array('key1a' => 'value1a'), 
    'key2' => array('value2'), 
    'key3' => 'value3'
);
```

---

### A different approach

Looking at what you want to do, you need to refactor your approach.

First change your controller pathing for ONLY the comment.

```
blog_details:
    path:      /{id}/details
    defaults: { _controller: "BlogBundle:Blog:details" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
comment_report:
    path:     /{comment}/report
    defaults: { _controller: "BlogBundle:Blog:report" }
    methods:  [POST]
```

Next create a form instance for your modal, this will allow you use the FormInstance for rendering and validating the submitted form elsewhere. Ensuring that all of the validation occurs and you're not having to update different scripts for the same form.

```php
/* /src/Form/CommentReportForm.php */

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class CommentReportForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $builder
             ->add('reason', Form\ChoiceType::class [
                'choices' => [
                     'Inappropriate Content' => 'Inappropriate Content',
                     'Spam' => 'Spam',
                     'Racism' => 'Racism',
                     'Nudity' => 'Nudity',
                     'Other' => 'Other'
                ]
            ])
             ->add('message', Form\TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\Length(['min' => 10]),
                    new Assert\NotBlank(),
                ],
            ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
       return 'report_comment_form';
    }
}
```

Next, update your Controller actions accordingly.

```php
public function detailsAction(Request $request, Blog $blog)
{
    if (!$user = $this->getUser()) {
        //this should be handled in your firewall configuration!!!!
        return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_login');
    }
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $add_comment = new CommentaireBlog();
    $add_comment->setBlog($blog);
    $add_comment->setUser($user);
    $add_comment->setDate(new \DateTime());

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($add_comment)
        ->add('contenu', TextareaType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //Symfony form sets values for the model by_reference
        $em->persist($add_comment);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_details', array('id' => $blog->getId()));
    }

    /*
    * create the report form
    */
    $reportForm = $this->createForm(\App\Form\CommentReportForm::class);
    $reportForm->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('blog/details.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'comment' => $add_comment,
        'blog' => $blog,
        'comments'=> $em->getRepository(CommentaireBlog::class)->findByBlog($blog),
        /*
         * give the report form a different name in twig
         */
        'report_form' => $reportForm->createView(),
    ));

}
```

```php
public function reportAction(Request $request, CommentaireBlog $comment)
{
    $reportForm = $this->createForm(\App\Form\CommentReportForm::class);
    $reportForm->handleRequest($request);
    /** @var array|string[message, reason] */
    $reportData = $reportForm->getData();
    /*
      array( 'reason' => 'value', 'message' => 'value' )
     */
    dump($reportData);
    if ($reportForm->isSubmitted() && $reportForm->isValid()) {
        //send email

        //redirect to success message
    }
    //display an error message
}
```

Lastly update your view to support the new form in your modal.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  {{ form_start(report_form, { action: path('comment_report', { comment: comment.id }) })
  {{ form_label(report_form.reason) }}
  {{ form_widget(report_form.reason) }}
  <div class="form-group">
      {{ form_label(report_form.message) }}
      {{ form_widget(report_form.message) }}
  </div>
  {{ form_end(report_form) }}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
</div>
```

---

As a recommendation, I strongly urge you to record the report submissions in the database, to function as a case log and status of the reports. My approach will get you most of the way there, you would just need to create your `App\Entity\CommentReport` entity, with an optional association to the `CommentaireBlog` entity. Which would be passed to the form and adding the `data_class` to the form options resolver, mimicking what you have done in your other database forms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wrote your `path` call like that, but there should not be any round brackets about the variables you want to use in your route. The following code should work:

```
<a 
  href="{{ path('comment_report', { 'msg': form.reportmessage.value ,'type': form.reportreason.value, 'id': comment.id  }) }}" 
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary">
     Send message
</a>
```

Comment: i dont know i still learning symfony but i tried with ur code before i post this and it says : Neither the property "reportmessage" nor one of the methods "reportmessage()", "getreportmessage()"/"isreportmessage()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".

Comment: Well, then your `form` variable (wherever that comes from?) does not have such a property. Where did you define it?

Comment: i used an other generated  form to add comments in  the same twig page
{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_end(form)}}
is that the problem ?

Comment: That depends - does your form contain that reportmessage field?

Comment: no that form is for adding comments in database  it has nothing to do with the reportmessage and report reason field

Comment: hey i just updated my code and exactly what im trying to do i hope it makes some sense now